# Screenshot is not taken in TestNG listeners TestFailure() method

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm trying to take a screen shot in selenium webdriver when my test case assertion gets failed. Please find the below code for your reference.

```
public abstract class TestChromeDriver {


    public WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver(){
        return driver;
    }

    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeTest
    public void browserInitialize(String browser){
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Aishu\\Test_Java\\TestNG Groups\\External JAR's\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }   
    }
    @AfterTest  
    public void tearDownDriver(){
    if(driver != null){
        driver.quit();
        }
    }   
}

public class TestClass extends TestChromeDriver{

    @Test
    public void tc1_functionality(){
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Assert.assertEquals("test", driver.getCurrentUrl().toLowerCase().contains("selenium"));
    }
}

public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result){

         Object currentClass = result.getInstance();
          WebDriver driver = ((TestChromeDriver)currentClass).getDriver();

              File file = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
              try {
                  FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File("D:\\Aishu\\Test_Java\\TestNG Groups\\Images"+result.getName()+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }
```

The assertion gets failed in my test method. But even though the screen shot is not taken for the failed assertion. Not Sure what I'm doing wrong in the `TestNG.XML` file or even in the code level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="suite1">

<listeners>
<listener class-name = "org.test.chromeDriver.TestListener"/>
</listeners>

<test name="chromeTest">
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
<classes>
<class name = "org.test.chromeDriver.TestChromeDriver"/>
<class name = "org.test.chromeDriver.TestClass"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i saw your code but finds no issue. i think, it should work fine.

Comment: @optimist_creeper - It is not taking screenshots, and I don't see any error messages as well

Comment: @Aishu - How are you concluding that the screenshots are not being taken ? Have you tried setting up debug points in your code to check if the screenshot taking piece of code is being executed ? Have you also ruled out if the file creation is failing due to permission issues etc ? Maybe you can try taking the screenshots as bytes and print it just for debugging purposes.